# Select rows with equal values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to do in Laravel?

1) get from table rows where `user_id` has the equal values?

2) return sum of `some_amount` values from this selected rows

```
Table:
 - id;
 - user_id;
 - some_amount;
```

Table has bunch of certificates with some amount of money that belongs to different users. I need to find all certificates that belongs to one user (one user can have few certificates) and count how much money he have from all his certificates

Comment: What have you tried and what is the use case for this? Are you trying to get the sum amount for a particular user or a query over the whole table that performs this?

Comment: Table has bunch of certificates with some amount of money that belongs to different users. I need to find all certificates that belongs to one user (one user can have few certificates) and count how much money he have from all his certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you aren't looking for a solution to query this for an individual user, it sounds like you want to group by the user and sum the result of certificates.

The answer from @PhilCross is pretty close, you'd just need to modify it to add the group clause and remove the where condition. Something like this:

```
ModelName::groupBy('user_id')->sum('some_amount');
```

or

```
\DB::table('table_name')->groupBy('user_id')->sum('some_amount');
```

Generally eloquent or the query builder will have a method that relates to how you would do this in raw SQL.
I find it helpful to write out or think about how I would write the raw SQL and then slowly fill the eloquent or query builder in from that.

Comment: maybe you can tip me how to return this sum of `some amount` for every user separate? because in this case it returns me just for one user

Comment: @PhilippNoris - can you please clarify what you're wanting? This `groupBy()` will sum the amount for each user individually, what are you trying to say when you mention *it returns me just for one user*?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Model:

```
ModelName::where('user_id', 1)->sum('some_amount')
```

If you're using the query builder:

```
\DB::table('table_name')->where('user_id', 1)->sum('some_amount');
```

This is the documentation for the query builder:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Models: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent
Model Relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships
Collections: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

Comment: This I know, but my task a bit different, I'm not providing user_id value, it should find certificates that has same values. For example John Doe has 4 certificates and Timothy has 2 certificates, and I need to find sum how much money received John Doe from all his certificates and Tomothy as well separately

Comment: @PhilippNorris when your comment is more informative than your question, it's time to drastically revise your question